# Разделение массива по чётным и нечётным индексам

Tags: javascript, массивы, double

Создать массив А с 20 числами типа double. Из массива А сформировать массив B. В начале массива В расположить элементы,которые в массиве А имеют нечетный индекс, а в конце расположить элементы массива А с четным индексом. Менять последовательность чисел запрещено. Вывести элементы массива В по 10 в каждом ряду

Comment: **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи.** Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: В JavaScript нет типа double.

Answer (score 3):

Для выборки отдельных элементов из массива можно воспользоваться методом [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Callback функция этого метода вторым параметром принимает индекс массива, таким образом для получения элементов с четным или нечетным индексом нужно проверить условие `index % 2 == 0` либо `index % 2 != 0`.

Для сцепки между собой полученных массивом можно воспользоваться методом [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

В итоге код может выглядеть так:

```
var b = a.filter((_, index)=>index%2!=0).concat(a.filter((_, index)=>index%2==0));
```